# Current Date and time not being added to redirected output filename from Windows Batch file for hours 0-9

Tags: batch-file

I'm facing issue when I want the output of command (executing a JAR with command line parameter) being executed from a Batch file be sent to a file that has current date and Time in its name.

Content of my batch file looks as follows

```
    @ECHO OFF


    SET HOUR=%time:~0,2%

    SET dtStamp9=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2% 
    SET dtStamp24=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

    if "%HOUR:~0,1%" == " " (SET dtStamp=%dtStamp9%) else (SET dtStamp=%dtStamp24%)

    echo %dtStamp%

    java -Xmx1024M -jar ..\lib\My.jar JobName Param1>\myfolder\\logs\process_EST.%dtStamp%.log
```

When I execute the batch file between hours 0 - 9, although the `echo %dtStamp%` is giving correct value say `20180718_020849` but the JAR execution is failing because for some reason value of `%dtStamp%` is not be substituted correctly on the java command and it causes `.log` to be treated as a second parameter to `My.jar`.
However, for hours 10 to 23, the same Batch file works perfectly fine.

Any help in this regards would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is a trailing space in the `SET dtStamp9=...` command line, which becomes part of the value...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl for pointing that out , that was the problem. Removing the trailing space fixed the my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line:

```cmd
SET dtStamp9=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
```

there is a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, but in the line:

```cmd
SET dtStamp24=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
```

there is none.

This space is then causing problems with the line:

```cmd
java -Xmx1024M -jar ..\lib\My.jar JobName Param1>\myfolder\\logs\process_EST.%dtStamp%.log
```

because `.log` is seen as another argument as there is the said <kbd>SPACE</kbd> before.

To fix that, you can of course just remove the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

However, you could do other things to avoid such problems:

- use the quoted `set` syntax, like `set "VAR=Value"`, hence trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> do no longer become part of the value, and the quotation marks do not too;
- quote the log file path in order to protect such containing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>;

So applied to your code this means:

```cmd
@ECHO OFF
SET "HOUR=%time:~0,2%"
SET "dtStamp9=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%" 
SET "dtStamp24=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"
if "%HOUR:~0,1%" == " " (SET "dtStamp=%dtStamp9%") else (SET "dtStamp=%dtStamp24%")
echo %dtStamp%
java -Xmx1024M -jar "..\lib\My.jar" JobName Param1>"\myfolder\logs\process_EST.%dtStamp%.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you make the whole process easier and use a reliable method of setting the date stamp, which is not affected by user or region settings:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "dtStamp="
For /F "Tokens=1-6Delims=/: " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined dtStamp Set "dtStamp=%%A%%B%%C_%%D%%E%%F"
```

You can then place your `Java` command line below it using `%dtStamp%.log` and it will not matter what time of day the script is ran!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the command into variable and then `CALL` it:

```
SET "exec=java -Xmx1024M -jar ..\lib\My.jar JobName Param1>\myfolder\logs\process_EST.%dtStamp%.log"

CALL %exec%
```